# How to handle OTP screen in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

How to handle OTP screen which is generated from API in Selenium Webdriver-

[image]

Comment: Try to get element id or name by using the DevTools
To access the DevTools, open a web page or web app in Google Chrome. Either:

Select the Chrome menu Chrome Menu at the top-right of your browser window, then select Tools > Developer Tools.
Right-click on any page element and select Inspect Element.

Answer (score 1):

```
String userProfile= "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\";

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+userProfile);

options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

The above code working fine for Automate the **OTP** verification sites, just create your local chrome trusted one time and call same browser using above code for testing. It's quite cool.